# Is there a way to provide a template for Blazor logging output?

Tags: templates, logging, blazor, blazor-webassembly

When I print in Blazor WebAsm using `Console.WriteLine` I will get single line, but when I use logger I will get two lines. I would like to customize the output template, and get rid of the first line.

Is there a way to do this? How?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/console-log-formatter

Comment: @BrianParker, thank you, but relevant methods are marked as not supported in browser, and even if I try, I get exception because of the platform (i.e. browser).